# Only the first node in my Linked Listed is printing

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to build a basic linked list.  I call the function appendNode() four times with different values and ONLY one prints to the screen.  How do I get all four to print?  how is it stuck at the first?

```
void NumberList::appendNode(double num)
{
    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodePtr;

    newNode = new ListNode; //allocating memory .
    newNode->value = num;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    //no nodes, so this becomes the head.

    if (!head) //if not null or zero.  so if it returns anything BUT zero, this statement executes.
        head = newNode; //the head is now pointing to the newly created newNode.
    else // so the last newNode has already been set to the head and now we're at this statement.
    {
        nodePtr = head; // assigning the next node to the head, also the same address of that first node.
        while (nodePtr->next) //moving passed anything with a NULL until it reaches somthing Other than NULL.
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            //insertion at the end.
            nodePtr->next = newNode;
        }   
    }
}
void NumberList::displayNode()
{
    ListNode *nodePtr; // for traversing
    nodePtr = head;
    while (nodePtr)
    {
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes using debug mode on IDEs help to understand program flow which solves problems like these as sometimes things are not coded as one should... try understanding the flow of program and what is happening at each step.. you will be able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where there are existing elements in the list, your "appending to the end" logic is incorrect. You are trying to append the `newNode` every time in the loop.

You need to append *only* when the end is reached:

```
if(!head)
    head = newNode;
else
{
    nodePtr = head;
    while (nodePtr->next) 
    {
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }   
    //insertion at the end. (outside the loop)
    nodePtr->next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: No worries. Make sure to step through your code, and draw out the links between the nodes as you do that. It'll help you understand what's going on much better.

Answer (score 1):

When `head` is not NULL, you are performing `nodePtr->next = newNode;` in the wrong place.  After adding the 1st node to the list to set `head`, then on subsequent adds `head` is not NULL but `head->next` is NULL so your loop is never entered to add `newNode` to the list, so the list does not grow, and you leak the new node.  As such, when iterating a non-empty list at a later time, such as for printing, `head->next` is always NULL, so only the `head` node is processed.

The `nodePtr->next = newNode;` statement needs to be performed *after* the loop has found the last node in the list, not *while* the loop is looking for the last node:

```cpp
void NumberList::appendNode(double num)
{
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode; //allocating memory
    newNode->value = num;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (!head)
        head = newNode;
    else
    {
        ListNode *nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next)
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }   
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

That being said, the code can be greatly simplified so you don't have to separate the logic into 2 branches at all:

```cpp
class ListNode
{
public:
    double value;
    ListNode *next;

    ListNode(double num) : value(num), next(NULL) {}
};
```

```cpp
void NumberList::appendNode(double num)
{
    ListNode **nodePtr = &head;
    while (*nodePtr) {
        nodePtr = &((*nodePtr)->next);
    }
    *nodePtr = new ListNode(num);
}
```